# Selecting java Automation testing tools for web application

Tags: java, automated-tests

I am very new to web automation testing tools. I want to automate my functional tests of web.

Please suggest me a few number of web automated testing tools. I want to use Java to write my automated testing tool.

I have visited the following site to select a good tool, but as I have no idea it is difficult to select a suitable tool for me.
http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools

Can any one suggest me a good tool for web testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For web testing, use Selenium (WebDriver) It's probably best tool for this purpose out there on [**GoogleCode**](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/)

You can find lot of examples on google, and documentation on  [**seleniumhq.org**](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)  its quite helpful for starters.

Comment: Ok thanks, another question is java automation testing for GUI which tools I need to use...

Answer (score 32):

**Web Application Testing Tools**

[Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) is widely used portable software testing framework for web applications. Selenium provides a record/playback tool for authoring tests without learning a test scripting language.

Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of their browser. It is also the core technology in countless other browser automation tools, APIs and frameworks.

[Anteater](http://freshmeat.net/projects/anteater-ant/) is a
testing framework designed around Ant, from the Apache Jakarta Project.
It is basically a set of Ant tasks for the functional testing of Web
sites and Web services (functional testing being: hit a URL and ensure
the response meets certain criteria). One can test HTTP parameters,
response codes, XPath, regexp, and Relax NG expressions. Anteater also
includes HTML reporting (based on junitreport) and a hierarchical
grouping system for quickly configuring large test scripts. When a Web
request is received, Anteater can check the parameters of the request
and send a response accordingly. This makes it useful for testing SOAP
and XML applications.

The ability to wait for incoming HTTP messages is something unique to
Anteater, which makes it especially useful when building tests for
applications that use high level SOAP-based communication, like ebXML or
BizTalk. Applications written using these protocols usually receive SOAP
messages and send back a meaningless response. It is only later that
they inform the client, using an HTTP request on the client, about the
results of the processing. These are the so-called asynchronous SOAP
messages, and are the heart of many high-level protocols based on SOAP
or XML messages.

Written in Java, [HttpUnit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/httpunit/) emulates the
relevant portions of browser behavior, including form submission,
Javascript, basic HTTP authentication, cookies, and automatic page
redirection, and allows Java test code to examine returned pages either
as text, an XML DOM, or containers of forms, tables, and links.

[jWebUnit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jwebunit/) is a Java
framework which facilitates creation of acceptance tests for Web
applications. It provides a high-level API for navigating a Web
application combined with a set of assertions to verify the
application's correctness. This includes navigation via links, form
entry and submission, validation of table contents, and other typical
business Web application features. It utilizes HttpUnit behind the
scenes. The simple navigation methods and ready-to-use assertions allow
for more rapid test creation than using only JUnit and HttpUnit.

[Bugkilla](http://freshmeat.net/projects/bugkilla/) is a tool set to
create, maintain, execute, and analyze functional system tests of Web
applications. Specification and execution of tests is automated for both
the Web frontend and business logic layers. One goal is to integrate
with existing frameworks and tools (an Eclipse Plugin exists)

[The Grinder](http://freshmeat.net/projects/grinder/), a Java
load testing framework freely available under a BSD-style Open Source
license, makes it easy to orchestrate the activities of a test script in
many processes across many machines, using a graphical console
application. Test scripts make use of client code embodied in Java
plugins. Most users of The Grinder do not write plugins themselves; they
use one of the supplied plugins. The Grinder comes with a mature plugin
for testing HTTP services, as well as a tool which allows HTTP scripts
to be automatically recorded.

[Jameleon](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jameleon/) is an
automated testing tool that separates applications into features and
allows those features to be tied together independently, creating test
cases. These test cases can then be data-driven and executed against
different environments. Jameleon breaks applications into features and
allows testing at any level, simply by passing in different data for the
same test. Because Jameleon is based on Java and XML, there is no need
to learn a proprietary technology.

It's an acceptance testing tool for testing the functionality provided
by applications, and currently supports the testing of Web applications.
It differs from regular HttpUnit and jWebUnit in that it separates
testing of features from the actual test cases themselves.  If I
understand it correctly, you write the feature tests separately and then
script them together into a reusable test case.  Incidentally, you can
also make these test cases data-driven, which gives an easy way of
running specific tests on specific environments.

The framework has a plugin architecture, allowing different functional
testing tools to be used, and there is a plugin for testing Web
applications using HttpUnit/jWebUnit. The test case scripting is done
with XML and [Jelly](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jakarta_jelly/).

Jameleon combines [XDoclet](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xdoclet/), [Ant](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ant/) and Jelly to provide a
potentially powerful framework for solid functional testing of your
Webapp. It strikes a good balance between scripting and coding, and
allows you to set up multiple inputs per test by providing input via CSV
files. Along with the flexibility come a complexity and maintenance
overhead, but you are getting your Webapp tested for you.

[LogiTest](http://freshmeat.net/projects/logitest/) is the
core application in the LogiTest suite. LogiTest is designed to aid in
the testing of Web site functionality. It currently supports HTTP and
HTTPS protocols, GET and POST methods, multiple document views, custom
headers, and more. The LogiTest application provides a simple graphical
user interface for creating and playing back tests for testing
Internet-based applications.

[Solex](http://freshmeat.net/projects/solex/) is a set of
Eclipse plugins providing non-regression and stress tests of Web
application servers. Test scripts are recorded from Internet browsers,
thanks to a built-in Web proxy.   For some Web applications, a request
depends on a previous server's response. To address such a requirement,
Solex introduces the concept of extraction and replacement rules. An
extraction rule tied to an HTTP message's content will bind an extracted
value with a variable. A replacement rule will replace any part of an
HTTP message with variable content.

The tool therefore provides an easy way to extract URL parameters,
Header values, or any part of a request or a response, bind their values
with variables, and then replace URL parameters, Header values, or any
part of a request with the variable content. The user has the ability to
add assertions for each response. Once a response has been received, all
assertions of this response will be called to ensure that it is valid.
If not, the playback process is stopped. Several kinds of rules and
assertions are provided. The most complicated ones support regular
expressions and XPath.

[Tclwebtest](http://freshmeat.net/projects/tclwebtest/) is a
tool for writing automated tests of Web applications in Tcl. It
implements some basic HTML parsing functionality to provide comfortable
commands for operations on the HTML elements (most importantly forms) of
the result pages.

[TagUnit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/tagunit/) is a framework
through which custom tags can be tested inside the container and in
isolation from the pages on which they will ultimately be used. In
essence, it's a tag library for testing tags within JSP pages. This
means that it is easy to unit test tags, including the content that they
generate and the side effects that they have on the environment, such as
the introduction of scripting variables, page context attributes,
cookies, etc.

[Web Form Flooder](http://freshmeat.net/projects/formflood/)
is a Java console utility that analyzes a Web page, completes any forms
present on the page with reasonable data, and submits the data. It
crawls links within the site in order to identify and flood additional
forms that may be present.   It is great for load testing of Web forms,
checking that all links work and that forms submit correctly.

[XmlTestSuite](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xmltestsuite/)
provides a powerful way to test Web applications. Writing tests requires
only knowledge of HTML and XML. The authors want XmlTestSuite to be
adopted by testers, business analysts, and Web developers who don't have
a Java background.  XmlTestSuite supports "test-driven development".  It
lets you separate page structure from tests and test data.  It can also
verify databases.  It's like JWebUnit, but has simple XML test
definitions and reusable pages.

Comment: Well answered and explained

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is the most mature and widely used tool for web UI testing (open source anyway, though I don't think there are much better proprietary tools either). Its biggest advantage is that it uses the actual browser engine and can therefore be used to test AJAX-heavy pages as well.

Comment: but what makes selenium doesnt fit others requirements are : Focus need to be properly concerned. And multiple instance call in one pc is a problem. Isn't , @Michael?

Comment: @gumuruh I'm not sure what "Focus need to be properly concerned" is supposed to mean. Selenium does have functionality to se the focus via moveToElement(). And it's possible to run multiple instances on one Linux machine using Xvfb.