# Managed code for test Automation for Java based web application

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dom-events

The following might be a generic question, but I was to curious to learn if there are any possibilities

Currently there are many web applications and as part of test automation for them, several tools are being used for record and playback and such tools which are used for automation, will record the UI on the browser and while interacting with elements or controls on web page, the tools use xpath or some other identifiers to generate code and such code is less stable and may not provide seamless interaction. Many a time, the playback of such scripts sticks and may not be able to find the element or may not be able to click the controls such as buttons or checkboxes or images or radio buttons or hyperlinks etc. Sometimes, the automation script execution/playback goes unbelievably slow or times out.

Often, the web UI automation scripts lose focus during playback. For example the

1. script must a click button A, but it clicks the adjacent buttonB,
2. the script must be clicking menu itemA, but clicks menuItemB to launch pageB instead of page A

which indicates that the script execution and application are going out of sync

The behavior of these scripts also differs in different browsers. The recording is only possible when the application is up and a particular page launched

So, I was just curious to know if there is any way to overcome the problems mentioned above.

I mean is it possible to hand code the scripts in such way the recording is not required, but the scripts are ready with a managed code even before the application/web page is not launched, thus keeping a seamless and stable interactions between the script and the browsers/web applications.

Comment: what i mean by managed code, is to have somekind of proxy classes autogenerated per per web page and use them in the scripts, to keep the interaction between script and browser/application intact, without having to make changes even if application functionality changes in the future

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379816/selecting-java-automation-testing-tools-for-web-application  may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Selenium?  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

It allows for automation and you can record the scripts using the GUI, but then you can manually modify the code generated for the scripts to point to the right things if the recorder gets it wrong.

Not sure if this fits with what you are trying to do, but I've used it before to automate some tasks on a browser and it worked really well.

Comment: selenium also doesn't provide seamless support. the selenium script from browser to browser vary. the DOM or HTML xpath is different if selenium to be used