# Testing rest services by using the client

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest

I have been an old school type of programmer and didn't really use tests in my projects. I want to change that now but since it's not an industrial project but my own I would like to ask:

Is there any problem with using the client to test my Rest service?

Why would I need to write a unit test to test the rest backend and then write a client when I can just extend the client?

Is there any convention that the testing language should be the same as the implementing language ? I am talking about Java rest and JS client.

I think this will make my approach much more agile and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Why would I need to write a unit test to test the rest backend and then write a client when I can just extend the client?`

Basically in Test Cases you test **everything** while a client may use only a subset of the interface and will never hit a possible bug.

`Is there any convention that the testing language should be the same as the implementing language ?`

No. But there are very good tools (even automatic generation) that snaps into the Java IDE, [Selecting java Automation testing tools for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379816/selecting-java-automation-testing-tools-for-web-application) .